# how to monitor the CPU usage of a PHP script

Tags: php

how can I do that?

how do share hosts limit the CPU time for a script?

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538251/how-can-i-get-the-cpu-and-memory-useage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a native method for doing this in PHP so I would try phpSysInfo as it provides information on CPU, uptime, ethernet, SCSI, IDE, etc.  http://phpsysinfo.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

Web hosts have several means of limiting PHP (and how much memory a child web server process can consume). Commonly, PHP is limited by the max execution time configured in php.ini (which is also set so that functions like set_time_limit() can't override it. Additionally, hosts use things `ulimit` to limit the amount of memory / time that any given process can consume.

If not configured to restrict PHP to individual webroots, you can open `/proc/self` and have access to statistics about your process. Note, you won't be able to do that, or use phpsysinfo if open_basedir is in effect.