# How can I get the CPU and Memory useage

Tags: php, cron, cpu-usage

I want to know the memory and CPU usage in php, because I'm using cronejobs sometimes the CPU is overloaded so in this case I don't wan to start more process, I just want to skip this cron.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think better way is get *load avarage*, because it depends not only on CPU, but on HDD speed also.

Here is a doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-getloadavg.php

Comment: There is three values what is that?
Load Averages  0.48 0.76 0.43

Comment: First number is computed during last minute, second is computed during last 5 minutes and last numbers is computed during last 15 minutes. These numbers determine how much occupy a cores. So if you have single core and this numbers below 1.0 then your system is full responsibility. All info is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_(computing)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at this library http://phpsysinfo.sourceforge.net/

Demo: http://phpsysinfo.sourceforge.net/phpsysinfo/index.php?disp=dynamic

**Edit:** This was taken from Stephen's comment. I put it here just so that it gets enough exposure for people to read.

> Just a note: this library isn't too snappy. I couldn't find a way to
>   just return CPU or just ram, it returns EVERYTHING, hardware list,
>   network stats, hd usage, os info, pretty much everything you can think
>   of. This takes it about 4 seconds to complete so it may not be the
>   best option if you want a constantly updating value using ajax or
>   something of the sort.

Comment: Just a note: this library isn't too snappy. I couldn't find a way to just return CPU or just ram, it returns EVERYTHING, hardware list, network stats, hd usage, os info, pretty much everything you can think of. This takes it about 4 seconds to complete so it may not be the best option if you want a constantly updating value using ajax or something of the sort.

Comment: @Stephen Thanks for the heads up Stephen. I've quoted your comment in my answer. Just in case some people might miss it.

Answer (score 2):

[How to get Memory and CPU usage in PHP](http://www.tonylea.com/2012/how-to-get-memory-and-cpu-usage-in-php/)

Perfect simple examples.

--
Memory in procentage % ($mem[2]/1000 for used memory in MB)

```
function get_server_memory_usage(){

$free = shell_exec('free');
$free = (string)trim($free);
$free_arr = explode("\n", $free);
$mem = explode(" ", $free_arr[1]);
$mem = array_filter($mem);
$mem = array_merge($mem);
$memory_usage = $mem[2]/$mem[1]*100;

return $memory_usage;
}
```

-- CPU in procentage %

```
function get_server_cpu_usage(){

$load = sys_getloadavg();
return $load[0];

}
```

Comment: It will be very much great if you elaborate your answer with an example too.

Answer (score 1):

I recently have some issue to get CPU load and i feel like sharing it .

Here was my solution witch help me out :

My situation :

I've use Zend Framework 1.2 to build monitoring application and i want to get cpu load and show it on the page . after doing some research i found out i could use COM Object and query the Win OS with wmi so i put these code to my init function :

```
    /* Initialize action controller here */
    $this->wmi = new COM('winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}//./root/cimv2');

    if (!is_object($this->wmi)) {
        throw new GetInfoException('This needs access to WMI. Please enable DCOM in php.ini and allow the current user to access the WMI DCOM object.');
    }
```

- You could use it anywhere you want , i have use it in the init function beacuse of Zend structure .

And i added an Action and an function to use that wmi and get cpu load any time i want by calling that function .

```
public function cpuloadAction()
{
    echo json_encode($this->getLoad());
    exit();
}

private function getLoad() {

    // Time?
    if (!empty($this->settings['timer']))
        $t = new LinfoTimerStart('Load Averages');

    $load = array();
    foreach ($this->wmi->ExecQuery("SELECT LoadPercentage FROM Win32_Processor") as $cpu) {
        $load[] = $cpu->LoadPercentage;
    }
    //return round(array_sum($load) / count($load), 2) . "%";
    return (int)round(array_sum($load) / count($load), 2);
}
```

- beacuse i what real time data i put these code in a function Otherwise you could write it in single non Object Oriented PHP file.

Hope it help .