# determine how much resource used by a php script (cpu percentage and memory)

Tags: php, symfony, profiling, cpu-time, xhprof

I'm currently using `xhprof` library forked by [tideways.io](https://tideways.io/profiler/xhprof-for-php7-php5.6) for profiling `myscript.php` execution. From `xhprof`, i can get the `walltime`, `cputime`, `memoryusage`, and `peakmemoryusage`. I'm try to benchmark a symfony console - so i add `TIDEWAYS_ENABLE()` on its `ConsoleCommandEvent` and `TIDEWAYS_DISABLE` on its `ConsoleTerminateEvent`.

Questions:

1. How can i determine whether `myscript.php` consume how many percentage of cpu ? Can i just count the percentage as `cpuusage = cputime / realtime` like stated [here on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/648704/how-are-cpu-time-and-cpu-usage-the-same/648706#648706) ?
2. Given a `memoryusage (mu)` and `peakmemoryusage (pmu)` from `xhprof` profiler, how do i convert or calculate its `ram` usage ? (`top` result show much higher than `memoryusage` but somehow near `peakmemoryusage` value, so can i say that `ram` usage is the value of `peakmemoryusage` ?

Notes:

- It's different with this [How can I get the CPU and Memory useage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538251/how-can-i-get-the-cpu-and-memory-useage), because what i want is not the `system load`. p.s there might multiple `scripts.php` running at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you want to determine using the data, but if you're trying to do any comparative analysis (e.g. "when I remove this loop, it's 25% faster and uses 10% less memory") I'd suggest that you use https://blackfire.io/.

It's easy to setup and easy to use. It also offers automatic comparative analysis between requests. It also does multiple passes internally to make sure that external factors are averaged-out.

I can't really say whether the CPU and memory usage data is accurate. It is definitely accurate relatively to other data in blackfire - so works great if you just need to compare it. You should take it with a grain of salt if you need absolute numbers though (how many scripts like this is it safe to run on 4GB server?). But I'd say it's pretty accurate. It's definitely much better than xdebug's profiller.

Comment: Actually i've no issue to retrieve the `cputime` - i'm using  [xhprof](https://github.com/tideways/php-profiler-extension) forked by [tideways.io](https://tideways.io) instead of [blackfire.io](https://blackfire.io). What makes me curios is it possible to calculate a `script.php` cpu usage just like showed up in command like `top` or `htop` in percentage just from `cputime` value ?

Comment: oops, sorry I misunderstood what you asked